# Customised EditAction Buttons don't trigger events

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableviewcontroller with an Edit button in the navbar This has been overridden to show Options and Done  instead of the Edit and Done..

In my viewDidLoad function I have...

```
    // Display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    // change initial text from Edit to Options
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.title = "Options"
```

I also have the following...

```
override func setEditing (editing:Bool, animated:Bool)
{
    //set different text for Edit and Done
    super.setEditing(editing,animated:animated)
    if(self.editing)
    {
        self.editButtonItem().title = "Done"
    }else
    {
        self.editButtonItem().title = "Options"
    }
}
```

For completeness this is my code for the edit action.

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch editingStyle {

    case .Delete:
        let context = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            //this is the top (first row)
            // Deleting without warning
            let indexPathToDelete = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
            let objectToDelete = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPathToDelete) as! NSManagedObject
            context.deleteObject(objectToDelete)

            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        } else {
            //we are deleted a row that is not the top row
            // we need to give a warning and if acknowledged then delele all rows from the selected row and all rows above it

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Are you sure? This will remove this and all logs above it.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in

            }
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Default) { (action) in

                for deleteindex in 0 ... indexPath.row {
                    let deleteIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: deleteindex, inSection: 0)
                    let objectToDelete = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(deleteIndexPath) as! NSManagedObject
                    context.deleteObject(objectToDelete)
                }

                do {
                    try context.save()

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

            // Dispatch on the main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
            }

        }
        break;

    default :
        return
    }

}
```

This works fine...

Now I've now added custom edit actions... the usual Delete + Export by adding this code...

```
//Override edit actions
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
    }

    let export = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Export") { (action, indexPath) in
        // export item at indexPath
    }

    export.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [delete, export]
}
```

And now when in Edit mode each cell now has two options Export and Delete but neither do anything when pressed.

I have a breakpoint at the line case .Delete but it is not being hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to place your deletion code into its Action:

```
// Override edit actions
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // You code for Deletion here... 

    }
```

Comment: Believe it or not as I was constructing the question this crossed my mind... so do I not need the override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { } anymore?

Comment: right, you will leave it empty and move the deletion code into the block of the "delete" Action